# Stockfish evaluation of a position from PGN

Tags: analysis, stockfish, programming, pgn, fen

I am trying to get Stockfish's evaluation of a board position(which is in PGN format) using command line.
I know it accepts board position in FEN format, but is there any way i can provide PGN format?
If no, how can i convert PGN format to FEN?
Is there any tool in Python which can help me out?

Comment: This is great, but is it possible to update the code for the latest version of the chess lib?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there are easy ways to do this. I'm going to briefly show you one quick way of doing it in python, using the [python-chess](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-chess) module.
If the in-code comments are not enough, feel free to ask for clarifications or possible extensions of the code:

To showcase a working example, I've taken a game between [Adams and Kasparov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1333302), you can download the PGN from the hyperlink. And our engine is the latest Stockfish available taken from the [official website](https://stockfishchess.org/).

Lets call it `PGNeval.py`:

```
import chess
import chess.uci
import chess.pgn
import sys

arguments = sys.argv
pgnfilename = str(arguments[1])

#Read pgn file:
with open(pgnfilename) as f:
    game = chess.pgn.read_game(f)

#Go to the end of the game and create a chess.Board() from it:
game = game.end()
board = game.board()

#So if you want, here's also your PGN to FEN conversion:
print 'FEN of the last position of the game: ', board.fen()

#or if you want to loop over all game nodes:
#while not game.is_end():
    #node = game.variations[0]
    #board = game.board() #print the board if you want, to make sure
    #game = node         

#Now we have our board ready, load your engine:
handler = chess.uci.InfoHandler()
engine = chess.uci.popen_engine('...\stockfish_8_x64') #give correct address of your engine here
engine.info_handlers.append(handler)

#give your position to the engine:
engine.position(board)

#Set your evaluation time, in ms:
evaltime = 5000 #so 5 seconds
evaluation = engine.go(movetime=evaltime)

#print best move, evaluation and mainline:
print 'best move: ', board.san(evaluation[0])
print 'evaluation value: ', handler.info["score"][1].cp/100.0
print 'Corresponding line: ', board.variation_san(handler.info["pv"][1])
```

Lets test it with the aformentioned game PGN, our command is:

`python PGNeval.py adams_kasparov_2005.pgn`

And here's the output I get:

`FEN of the last position of the game:  br3r2/5ppk/p2pp3/4b1BP/N3P3/q4P2/1PnQB3/1K4RR w - - 4 27
best move:  Qxc2
evaluation value:  -10.87
Corresponding line:  27. Qxc2 Rfc8`

Comment: Is there any way i can traverse to any node of a game(not just end node)?

Comment: yes, just loop over the nodes, I've added one way of doing this in the edit.

Comment: `variations` gives you all child nodes which you are re-assigning to `game` to traverse till end. Thanks phonon for your help.

Comment: my pleasure. Have fun playing around with this module, it's well written.